# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException after enable proguard [android]

Tags: android, apk

hi I use reflection method in my android code i run it working fine but when enable proguard to create a apk i get following Exception

```
10-28 10:53:22.368: W/System.err(21380): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showCaseView0
10-28 10:53:22.368: W/System.err(21380):    at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
10-28 10:53:22.368: W/System.err(21380):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:748)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at com.snovabits.mobile.andorid.app.game.ballon.BlowBallonActivity.b(Unknown Source)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at com.snovabits.mobile.andorid.app.game.ballon.c.run(Unknown Source)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
10-28 10:53:22.379: W/System.err(21380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
10-28 10:53:22.388: W/System.err(21380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 10:53:22.388: W/System.err(21380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-28 10:53:22.388: W/System.err(21380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-28 10:53:22.398: W/System.err(21380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-28 10:53:22.398: W/System.err(21380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDITED**

my proguard File

```
-dontwarn com.google.ads.util.*
```

Comment: Post your proguard file code.

Comment: -dontwarn com.google.ads.util.*

Comment: Try to write this line `-keep class com.google.ads.util.** { *; }`

Comment: not working this line i think actually problem is reflection method

Comment: Try to not your classes to include while generating proguard file. Write like this . `-keep class com.snovabits.mobile.andorid.app.game.ballon.BlowBallonActivity { *; }`